# React is not updating my state using useEffect and setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I have the following piece of code: The first one is a modal that holds some inputs:

```js
export const MessagesForm = (props) => {
    const [filteredMessages, setFilteredMessages] = useState(props.subject.messages);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [recordsPerPage] = useState(10);
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState(props.subject.messages);
    const indexOfLastRecord = currentPage * recordsPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstRecord = indexOfLastRecord - recordsPerPage;

    const nPages = Math.ceil(messages.length / recordsPerPage)

    const { handleSubmit, reset, register, control, getValues } = useForm({
        mode: 'onSubmit',
        defaultValues: {
            author: '',
            message: '',
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const newMessages = messages.slice(indexOfFirstRecord, indexOfLastRecord);
        setFilteredMessages(newMessages);
    }, [currentPage])


    const { remove } = useFieldArray({
        control,
        name: 'messages',
    });


    const handleDelete = (id) => {
        subjectService.deleteMessage(props.subject['_id']['$oid'], id);
        let filters = filteredMessages.filter((el) => el.id !== id);
        setFilteredMessages(filters);
    }

    const handleEdit = (index) => {
        const updatedMessage = getValues(`messages.${index}.message`);
        const updatedAuthor = getValues(`messages.${index}.author`);
        const messageId = getValues(`messages.${index}.id`);

        const body = {
            message: updatedMessage,
            author: updatedAuthor,
            id: messageId,
        };

        subjectService.updateMessage(props.subject['_id']['$oid'], body);
    }

    const onSubmit = async (formData) => {
        const body = {
            author: formData.author,
            message: formData.message,
        }
        subjectService.createMessage(props.subject['_id']['$oid'], body)
            .then(res => {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Success',
                    text: 'Message updated successfully',
                    icon: 'success',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Close',
                    confirmButtonColor: '#5CBDA5'
                }).then(props.onHide)
            })
    }

    return (
        <Modal
            {...props}
            animation
            size="lg"
            centered
        >
            <Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Title>
                    Mensajes
                </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <Pagination
                    nPages={nPages}
                    currentPage={currentPage}
                    setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}
                />
                {
                    filteredMessages.map((message, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div
                                key={index}
                                className="message-row"
                            >
                                <Form.Group
                                    className='row tes'
                                >
                                    <div className='col'>
                                        <Form.Label>Author</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            name='id'
                                            style={{ display: 'none' }}
                                            {...register(`messages.${index}.id`)}
                                            defaultValue={message.id}
                                        />
                                        <Form.Control
                                            type="text"
                                            name='author'
                                            {...register(`messages.${index}.author`)}
                                            defaultValue={message.author}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='col'>
                                        <Form.Label>Message</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control
                                            as="textarea"
                                            name='msg'
                                            {...register(`messages.${index}.message`)}
                                            defaultValue={message.message}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </Form.Group>
                                <div className='action-buttons'>
                                    <button className='btn btn-info' type="button" onClick={() => {
                                        Swal.fire({
                                            title: '¿Estás seguro?',
                                            text: "No podrás revertir esto",
                                            icon: 'warning',
                                            showCancelButton: true,
                                            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                                            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                                            confirmButtonText: 'Sí, guardarlo!'
                                        }).then((result) => {
                                            if (result.value) {
                                                handleEdit(index);
                                            }
                                        })
                                    }}><BiSave /></button>
                                    <button className='btn btn-danger' type="button" onClick={() => {
                                        Swal.fire({
                                            title: '¿Estás seguro?',
                                            text: "No podrás revertir esto!",
                                            icon: 'warning',
                                            showCancelButton: true,
                                            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                                            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                                            confirmButtonText: 'Sí, borrarlo!'
                                        }).then((result) => {
                                            if (result.value) {
                                                remove(index);
                                                handleDelete(message.id);
                                            }
                                        })
                                    }}><Trash /></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }

            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button
                    type="submit"
                    variant="primary"
                    form="hook-form"
                    onClick={() => {
                        if (props.action !== 'NEW') props.onHide();
                    }}
                >OK</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

And i'm using a functional component "Pagination" to paginate my modal:

```js
import React from 'react'

const Pagination = ({ nPages, currentPage, setCurrentPage }) => {

    const pageNumbers = [...Array(nPages + 1).keys()].slice(1)

    const nextPage = () => {
        if (currentPage !== nPages) setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)
    }
    const prevPage = () => {
        if (currentPage !== 1) setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)
    }

    return (
        <nav>
            <ul className='pagination justify-content-center'>
                <li className="page-item">
                    <a className="page-link"
                        onClick={prevPage}
                        href='#'>

                        Previous
                    </a>
                </li>
                {pageNumbers.map(pgNumber => (
                    <li key={pgNumber}
                        className={`page-item ${currentPage == pgNumber ? 'active' : ''} `} >

                        <a onClick={() => setCurrentPage(pgNumber)}
                            className='page-link'
                            href='#'>

                            {pgNumber}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                ))}
                <li className="page-item">
                    <a className="page-link"
                        onClick={nextPage}
                        href='#'>

                        Next
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Pagination
```

As my probably wrong understanding, by using the "useEffect" hook listening to the currentPage, it should update the state of my filteredMessages array, but it isn't
By using console log of the newMessages i'm actually obtaining the adequate output of data, but I don't quite know why is this happening only on the console...

Comment: Consider trimming the 220 lines of code a bit more to a more minimal MCVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `messages` in your useEffect but you haven't included that in the dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredMessages( messages.slice(indexOfFirstRecord, indexOfLastRecord));
}, [currentPage, messages]) // if you add it here it works, but read on
```

The problem with above code is it would now fire state updates anytime `messages` or `currentPage` changes. You could add some logic to look at the previous page but that just overcomplicates things.

My recommendation would be to not perform this type of logic in a `useEffect`. The best way to handle this scenario is to add this logic directly into `nextPage` and  `prevPage` event handlers:

```
const updateFilteredMessages = (page) =>   {
 const indexOfLastRecord = page * recordsPerPage;
 const indexOfFirstRecord = indexOfLastRecord - recordsPerPage;
 setFilteredMessages(messages.slice(indexOfFirstRecord, 
    indexOfLastRecord))
}
const nextPage = () => {
    if (currentPage !== nPages) {
      setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)
      updateFilteredMessages(currentPage + 1)
    }
}
```

All of this logic is related to the `nextPage` user action, so it's also a lot clearer to encapsulate it within a callback versus splitting off message filtering in the `useEffect`

I would construct the `nextPage` & `prevPage` handlers in your MessageForm component and pass them into Pagination (since you need access to the MessageForm local state)